# Oracle trigger on 2 tables : no data found

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Please help,I'm trying to allow/ban insertion into a table called 'vol' that has a foreign key (id_av) from another table 'avion'

- allow insertion : if avion.etat = 'disponible'
- ban it if it is different from 'disponible'
  for that I have created this trigger :

  ```
  create or replace trigger t
  before insert on vol 
  declare etat VARCHAR(10);
  BEGIN 
  select avion.etat into etat 
  from vol,etat
  where avion.id_av = vol.id_av;
  IF(etat <> 'disponible') 
  THEN 
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'insertion imposible');
  END IF;
  END t;
  /
  ```

  the result : the trigger is created but when I tryed to insert in vol it shows me these errors [image]

I've tryed also with JOIN..ON but didn't really worked out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
create or replace trigger t
  before insert on vol 
  for each row          --> edited
declare 
  etat VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN 
  -- MAX will prevent NO-DATA-FOUND 
  -- Also, you don't need join - use :NEW.ID_AV which is equal to currently inserted value
  select max(avion.etat)
  into etat 
  from avion
  where avion.id_av = :new.id_av;

  -- NVL because - if SELECT returns, nothing, you can't compare NULL with 'disponible'
  IF nvl(etat, 'x') <> 'disponible'
  THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'insertion imposible');
  END IF;
END t;
/
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it showed me an error : NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level trigger

Comment: Right; I missed the "FOR EACH ROW"; have a look at edited code, it is the 3rd line.